# Yet another "return-local-addr" - "function returns address of local variable"

Tags: c

I know, this is a very, very common question. 
I have read e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679558/warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable-wreturn-local-addr), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288871/function-returning-address-of-local-variable-error-in-c), [and this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312336/warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable-enabled-by-default%20%22%22). 
I used to think that returning the address of a local variable is a very bad idea. I used to think that you should better:

- allocate memory via e.g. malloc
- make the local variable static or
- pass the pointer as an argument

but then I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *  foo_1();
char ** foo_2();

int main() {

    char * p_1 = foo_1();
    char ** p_2 = foo_2();

    printf("\n [%s] \n", p_1);
    printf("\n [%s] \n", *p_2);

return 0;
}

char * foo_1() {
    char * p = "bar";
    return p;
}

char ** foo_2() {
    char * p = "bar";
    return &p;
}
```

I compile with -pedantic -pedantic-errors
and get the expected warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

but only for foo_2()! foo_1() works fine. Does any one know why and if this undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char * foo_1() {
    char * p = "bar";
    return p;
}
```

Here you are not returning the address of a local object but the pointer value of a pointer pointing to a string literal. String literals have static storage duration and it is fine to return a pointer to a string literal. When `foo_1` returns, `p` object is destroyed (automatic storage duration) but not `"bar"` (static storage duration).

Comment: I don't think that is standard behavior though.  clang does it, but IIRC at least some versions of gcc instantiate local strings on each function call.

Comment: @technosaurus it is standard behavior. *(c11, 6.4.5p6) "[...] The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence."*

Answer (score 3):

In `foo_2()` you are returning the adress of the local variable `p` which is why you get the warning.

In `foo_1()` you are returning the adress of the literal string, which is fine since it has static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

In `foo_2()`, you're returning the address of a (non-`static`) local variable. That address becomes indeterminate when the function returns, because the pointed-to object no longer exists -- thus the warning.

In `foo_1()`, you're returning the *value* of a local variable. There's no problem at all doing that; it's no worse than:

```
int foo_3(void) {
    int local = 42;
    return local;
}
```

which returns the *value* of `local`.

In `foo_1()`, since the variable whose value you're returning happens to be a pointer, you *could* still invoke undefined behavior if that value were questionable. For example:

```
int foo_1a(void) {
    char arr[] = "bar";
    char *p = arr; // or equivalently, &arr[0]
    return p;
}
```

Here you're still returning the value of a local variable (which is fine), but that value happens to be the address of another local variable, so the returned pointer value becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

A compiler is less likely to warn about `foo_1a` than about your `foo_2`, because it's less likely to be able to determine that the value of `p` when the return statement is executed is problematic. In fact the language does not require a diagnostic for this kind of thing. Compilers can do a reasonably good job of detecting and warning about some but not all instances of undefined behavior.

Bottom line: Your `foo_1()` function is well behaved. The pointer value it returns is the address of a string literal, which has static storage duration (i.e., it exists for the entire lifetime of the program).

However, since modifying that static array has undefined behavior, it would be wise to return the address as a `const char*` rather than as a `char*`, so the caller is less likely to attempt to modify the string literal. The `const` also serves as documentation for any human readers that the pointed-to value is not to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * p_1 = foo_1();
```

is OK. Dereferencing `p_1` is not a problem as long as you don't modify anything that `p_1` points to since `foo_1` returns a pointer to a string literal that is stored in read-only section of the program.

```
char ** p_2 = foo_2();
```

is not OK. Dereferencing `p_2` is cause for undefined behavior since `p_2` points to an object that's been deleted.